# How to restrict access to specific resources by client key in wso2 api manager for client credentials flow?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to implement server to server communication with wso2 api manager so my api can be used by thirdparty clients that can create their own apps and subscribe on my api. Also these clients should be restricted by specific set of resources - there is a set of organization ids and each specific client should have access only to some subset of ids. I figured out that client keys are stored in IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS table of WSO2AM_DB. I can attach to this DB and read client ids from separate service that will implement clientId-to-organizationIds mapping and with help of mediators I can call this service, check if organization id specified in url is allowed and add organization id property in access token so backend service can check one more time if organization is allowed. But I'm not sure if this is correct approach. Maybe there is something in wso2 that can help without such manipulations?

Answer (score 0):

> Also these clients should be restricted by specific set of resources

As you found out - the API manager authorizes calls based on the endpoint. The resources (e.g. specific ids) themselves should be authorized by the backend service. I am not sure that it's reasonable to enforce this level of authorization on the API manager (I'm not saying it's not possible, just it may be not flexible enough).

> Maybe there is something in wso2 that can help without such manipulations?

What I suggest is following - send a [JWT token](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Passing+Enduser+attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT) to the backend service. The backend service should do the authorization (based on the username, application, etc) without hard binding to the product database .

The linked documentation as well describes how to implement own token generator, so you could add additional claims to the jwt token (such as organization id, etc..).

Comment: If I have to check resource restriction on BE I still need to export somehow client ids from wso2 db and that is hard binding. I want to do resource restriction before actual BE service call and add orgId property in JWT because this is more efficient in terms of number BE calls and BE will not be aware of allowed resources - it will compare id in JWT and id from url param. What I want to do is to create separate service that will register clients and associated ids and after that export clients into wso2. So wso2 mediator can connect to this service and populate JWT with info I need.